# How to make dropdown menu with some specific details

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make advance dropdown menu with some details.

This is all about javascript, just js, no frameworks

I have to two dropdowns here, one is Services, the other is Projects. The problem here is I want that when I click on Services the sub menu at Services show, when I click on Projects the sub menu at Projects  show and the sub menu at Services hide and when I click outside both, sub menu hide too. I tried some codes but it didn't work as I expected. Thank you guys!

```
<nav>
    <h1 class="logo">Hiep</h1>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Serices</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Projects</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #000;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
}

.menu a {
    padding: 25px;
    display: block;
    }
    .menu a:hover {
        background: #fff;
        color: #333;
    }

.menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background: #000;
    width: 130%;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zoamkdru/4/

Comment: No javascript you say? If so, how are you targeting click events with html and css?

Comment: Sorry, just edited. Pure js

Comment: Okay, I just actually wrote an answer using css  :hover event.

Comment: I have updated my answer and put up a pure js and no more css:hover.

Answer (score 0):

Hhtml and CSS and Pure Javascript only... I did this in a rush. there's probably many other ways to perform this. But I used `data-active = true || false` attributes to set toggle values.

The same solution will be shorter with jquery... But I am sure that is what you're looking for in VanillaJS.

Run the snippet and check how it opperates

```js
(function()
{
    //Note JSON.pasrse("true" || "false") is used to convert string bool to actual bool datatype
    var dropdownTogglers = document.querySelectorAll("a.dropdown-toggler"); //get a list of toggle buttons
    var toggleElementsIds = ["services", "projects"]; //create a list of elements id to be toggled
    var otherLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".link");


    //helper function for getting an element by id
    function _id(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    //Target all other links
    for (var i = 0; i < otherLinks.length; i++) {
        otherLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < toggleElementsIds.length; i++) {
                _id(toggleElementsIds[i]).style.display = "none";
                _id(toggleElementsIds[i]).setAttribute("data-active", false);
            }
        });
    }
    _id("content-container").addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < toggleElementsIds.length; i++) {
            _id(toggleElementsIds[i]).style.display = "none";
            _id(toggleElementsIds[i]).setAttribute("data-active", false);
        }
    });

    //for all toggler buttons found,
    for(var i = 0; i < dropdownTogglers.length; i++)
    {
        //add a click event to that button
        dropdownTogglers[i].addEventListener("click",
            //get even as parameter
            function(event)
            {
                //use event to know which button is being clicked
                var el = event.target || src.target;

                //check if the button clicked is for services
                if (el.getAttribute("data-el") == toggleElementsIds[0])
                {
                    //check the current state of "data-active" of the services
                    if (!JSON.parse(_id(el.getAttribute("data-el")).getAttribute("data-active"))) {
                        //at this point services "data-active" is false
                        //set it to true
                        _id(el.getAttribute("data-el")).setAttribute("data-active", true);
                        //and ensure that the other toggling elements are hidden, or set to false
                        _id(toggleElementsIds[1]).setAttribute("data-active", false);
                    } else {
                        //at this point the services data-val was true
                        //set it to false
                        _id(el.getAttribute("data-el")).setAttribute("data-active", false);
                    }

                //check if the button clicked is for projects
                } else if (el.getAttribute("data-el") == toggleElementsIds[1])
                {
                    //check the current state of "data-active" of the projects
                    if (!JSON.parse(_id(el.getAttribute("data-el")).getAttribute("data-active"))) {
                        //at this point projects "data-active" is false
                        //set it to true
                        _id(el.getAttribute("data-el")).setAttribute("data-active", true);
                        //and ensure that the other toggling elements are hidden, or set to false
                        _id(toggleElementsIds[0]).setAttribute("data-active", false);
                    } else {
                        //at this point the projects data-val was true
                        //set it to false
                        _id(el.getAttribute("data-el")).setAttribute("data-active", false);

                    }
                }
                //after setting all data-active values, change their display status based on their values
                //call the toggle funtion
                ToggleOperations();
            }
        );
    }

    //perform toggle operations,
    //this function just sets css display properties of toggleElements based on their "data-active" true or false
    function ToggleOperations() {
        //Target all toggle elements
        for (var i = 0; i < dropdownTogglers.length; i++) {
            //if this toggle element "data-val" is true
            if (JSON.parse(_id(toggleElementsIds[i]).getAttribute("data-active")))
            {
                //set its display to block
                _id(toggleElementsIds[i]).style.display = "block";
            } else
            //if this toggle element "data-val" is false
            {
                //set the display to none
                _id(toggleElementsIds[i]).style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

```css
html, body{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 9000;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
}

.menu a {
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
}
.menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background: #000;
    width: 130%;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <h1 class="logo">Hiep</h1>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-toggler" data-el="services">Serices</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu" id="services" data-active="false">
                <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Contact</a></li>
        <li >
            <a class="dropdown-toggler" data-el="projects">Projects</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu" id="projects" data-active="false">
                <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="content-container" 
     style="width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: whitesmoke;">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want hover it, I want click event. It seems complicated.

Comment: I have also added some comments so that you could understand the JS code. Let me know what you think, I'll use other methods should you find this one not good for your scenario.

Comment: It works, but honestly the code is really complicated, I am just a beginner. Can you use jquery instead. Thanks.

Comment: Well. it isn't complicated. I think the first that I used lists and having to index [0] makes it harder for you to see what is going on. But you must learn to write good code. a code that looks long isn't necessarily complicated. I'll post a jquery solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Tried ':focus-within'. It might not be compatible with some browser though.

```
 .menu > li:focus-within ul {
    display: block !important;
 }
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 0 20px;
 background: #000;
}

h1 {
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

.menu li {
 position: relative;
}

.menu a {
 padding: 20px;
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

.menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background: #000;
    width: 130%;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.menu > li:focus-within ul {
   display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <h1 class="logo">Hiep</h1>
 <ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Services</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service 4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Projects</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Only services and Projects have dropdowns

Comment: It's a good way, but the problem here is that when click the link in sub menu, sub menu gone. I want its still there. Thanks

Comment: Updated to use `:focus-within` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple sample of how it can be done. I would normally use jQuery to mark the selector. It's been quite sometime since the last time I use vanilla js. This is the best I can do.

```js
var serviceTab = document.getElementById('serviceTab');
var projectTab = document.getElementById('projectTab');
var serviceSubMenu = document.getElementById('serviceSubMenu');
var projectSubMenu = document.getElementById('projectSubMenu');
var serviceSubMenuDisplayStatus = 0;
var projectSubMenuDisplayStatus = 0;

var content = document.getElementById('contentHere');


serviceTab.onclick = function() {

  if (serviceSubMenuDisplayStatus == 1) {
    serviceSubMenu.style.display = "none";
    serviceSubMenuDisplayStatus = 0;

  } else {
    serviceSubMenu.style.display = "block";
    serviceSubMenuDisplayStatus = 1;
    projectSubMenu.style.display = "none";
    projectSubMenuDisplayStatus = 0;
  }
}

projectTab.onclick = function() {

  if (projectSubMenuDisplayStatus == 1) {
    projectSubMenu.style.display = "none";
    projectSubMenuDisplayStatus = 0;
  } else {
    projectSubMenu.style.display = "block";
    projectSubMenuDisplayStatus = 1;
    serviceSubMenu.style.display = "none";
    serviceSubMenuDisplayStatus = 0;
  }
}

content.onclick = function() {
  if (serviceSubMenuDisplayStatus == 1) {
    serviceSubMenu.style.display = "none";
    serviceSubMenuDisplayStatus = 0;

  }
  if (projectSubMenuDisplayStatus == 1) {
    projectSubMenu.style.display = "none";
    projectSubMenuDisplayStatus = 0;
  } else {
    //do nothing. 
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #000;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu a {
  padding: 25px;
  display: block;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

.menu .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #000;
  width: 130%;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1 class="logo">Hiep</h1>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="serviceTab">Services</a>
      <!-- Add some ID here.  -->
      <ul class="sub-menu" id="serviceSubMenu">
        <!-- Add some ID here.  -->
        <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="projectTab">Projects</a>
      <!-- Add some ID here.  -->
      <ul class="sub-menu" id="projectSubMenu">
        <!-- Add some ID here.  -->
        <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="contentHere">
  click here
</div>
```

Comment: The problem here is when i click on other links outside dropdown menu, the dropdown menu still there. I want it hide when click on other links or outside. Thanks. Anyway, I want to see your jquery way. Thanks so much!

Comment: @HiepNguyen if you do not mind having a solution in jQuery, I would edit your question to mention that. “This is all about JavaScript...” kinda discourages the use of anything other than JS in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, please use jquery. Thanks

Comment: @nhk96 please help me.

Comment: @HiepNguyen See my answer below, with pure js.